# Get sheetnames from workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following code .I sucessfully extract data from each sheet in a workbook :

```
foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
{
    if (sheetName.Contains("_"))
    {
    }
    else
    {
         using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
         {
             var dataTable = new DataTable();
             string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
             con.Open();
             OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
             adapter.Fill(dataTable);
             ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);
         }
    }
}
```

My goal is to extract sheetname in `ds`.

I try the following code but it doesn't work

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT sheetName, * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
```

How should I modify it ?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result?

Comment: If your goal is to extract the sheetnames then obviously the function GetExcelSheetNames will provide you those. Can you tell us what you search exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a useless thing to do to me, but this should work:

```
string.Format("SELECT '{0}' as sheetName, * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
```

It just pasts the sheet name as the first field in the query.

That would assume you already know the name, which makes the method useless. OLEDB doesn't have a way to get the sheet names in Excel, so you would need another method to do so if you don't know the names.

---

For having single-quoted sheet names, use this:

```
string.Format("SELECT '{1}' as sheetName, * FROM [{0}]", sheetName, sheetName.Replace("'", "'''"));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using OfficeOpenXml?

```
 using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(file))
 {
     List<string> sheets = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
     var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[sheet];
     DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

     foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
     {
          tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
     }
     var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
     for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
     {
         var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, tbl.Columns.Count];
         var row = tbl.NewRow();
         foreach (var cell in wsRow)
         {
             row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
         }
         tbl.Rows.Add(row);
     }
     return tbl;
 }
```